# Chef Custom Resources : mutable property or an alternative

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-custom-resource

I read that as of `2016` OpsCode recommends against `LWRP` and the alternative `HWRP`.  They rather recommend to use `custom resources`.

While this makes sense it leaves a lot to be desired in terms of leveraging ruby (unless I've misunderstood?)

I would like to be able to modify an array based on some boolean properties.  I can then use that array to pass to the template, as in:

```
property :get_iptables_info, [TrueClass, FalseClass], default: false
property :get_pkglist, [TrueClass, FalseClass], default: false
property :cw_logs, Array, default: [], required: false

action :create do

  ruby_block 'cw_iptables' do
    block do
      new_resource.cw_logs.push({ "#{new_resource.custom_dir}/iptables/iptables.txt" => { "log_group_name" => new_resource.log_group_name+"/iptables"}})
    end
    action :run
    only_if {new_resource.get_iptables_info}
  end

  template "my_template" do
    variables ({:logstreams => cw_logs})
  end

end
```

Then in my template:

```
<% @logstreams.each_pair do |path, _object| %>
["#{path}"]
log_group_name = _object["log_group_name"]
<% end %>
```

The problem is that properties are `immutable`.  So I get the error:

```
RuntimeError
------------
ruby_block[cw_iptables] (/tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/custom_cw/resources/logs.rb line 43) had an error: RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array
```

What's the correct way to do this?  What's the correct way to write ruby code within the resource so that it's more modular and uses `methods/functions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutating properties inside a custom resource is generally a bad idea (there are exceptions but this isn't one of them). Better would be to use a local variable. Related, you don't need to use a ruby_block like that when you're already in a custom resource's action:

```
action :create do
  cw_logs = new_resource.cw_logs
  if new_resource.get_iptables_info
    cw_logs += [whatever extra stuff you want]
  end

  template "my_template" do
    variables logstreams: cw_logs
  end
end
```

Notably that's using `+=` instead of push which doesn't mutate the original. If you used `push` you would want `cw_logs = new_resource.cw_logs.dup` or similar.

Comment: I just saw that I can define a variable in the docs `prefix = '/opt/languages/node'` @ https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html

Comment: How can I make reusable functions in a resource?

Comment: To make functions available inside the action block, use the `action_class do ... end` helper. Any methods you define inside that block will be available from inside actions.